# Suppress Warning At Import

Tags: coq

I have a Coq project which uses the `Bits` library. At some places in the code I have

```
From Bits Require Import bits.
```

At that point I always get multiple warnings of the form

> Warning:
> New coercion path [natAsDWORD; DWORDtoVWORD] : nat >-> VWORD is ambiguous with existing
> [natAsQWORD; QWORDtoVWORD] : nat >-> VWORD. [ambiguous-paths,typechecker]

Now, my compile log is always full of warnings I really don't care about and I don't see if my code produces any important warnings.
So how do I suppress all warnings at imports, or at least these ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use the `Set Warnings` command to silence warnings.

```
Set Warnings "-ambiguous-paths".
From Bits Require Import bits.
Set Warnings "ambiguous-paths".
```

`ambiguous-paths` is inside the warning message itself.
I first tell it to remove it with a minus in front, and then I restore it afterwards because the command is global.

The `Warnings` flag is [documented here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:opt.Warnings).

Comment: Can I also globally disable that warning for the Bits library? It is something imported in most files, so I feel `Set Warnings` everywhere is quite verbose. I guess I could also reexport it from an own file and have the `Set Warnings` just in there?

Comment: I don't know how to do that either sorry. Your solution might be the only one.

Comment: You can unset the ambiguous paths warning directly in the `_CoqProject`, but then you will never be warned about it, which might bee too heavy handed.